# Why enum in typescript shows different value when assigned integers in descending order?

Tags: typescript, enums

I am new to typescript , and just trying the types in the type script.

For the enum data type I have tried the following code.

`enum colors {red=1,green=0,blue,white}; 
console.log(colors[1]);`

And it prints **'blue'** instead of **'red'**.

So can anyone explain what is the exact behavior of enum when assigning the value in descending order ?

Answer (score 2):

When things are not clear at runtime, it's usually a good idea to check the compiled js of your typescript code.
In this case:

```
var colors;
(function (colors) {
    colors[colors["red"] = 1] = "red";
    colors[colors["green"] = 0] = "green";
    colors[colors["blue"] = 1] = "blue";
    colors[colors["white"] = 2] = "white";
})(colors || (colors = {}));
```

As you can see the value of the enum for ordinal `1` is being assigned with red and then overridden with blue.

If you want to assign your own ordinals then you need to do it for all values of the enum:

```
enum colors { red=1, green=0, blue=2, white=3 };
```

Which compiles to:

```
var colors;
(function (colors) {
    colors[colors["red"] = 1] = "red";
    colors[colors["green"] = 0] = "green";
    colors[colors["blue"] = 2] = "blue";
    colors[colors["white"] = 3] = "white";
})(colors || (colors = {}));
```